# Can you add a dns name with three nodes, e.g. www.sudomain.maindomain.com?

Tags: apache, dns

We have a domain/subdomain naming system for our apps, e.g. mysubdomain1.mydomain1.com, and mysubdomain2.mydomain2.com.  But we would would like to implement urls where if it were preceded with a "www", e.g someone types "www.mysubdomain1.mydomain1", this would also bring them to the site.

But, I think we need to set up a dns entry for this, and I'm not sure this is possible - can you add "www.mysubdomain" as a dns entry for your main domain?

Answer (score 1):

As far as DNS goes, there's no problem. A google search found this article: http://techtitbits.com/2008/07/how-to-set-up-a-sub-subdomain/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

[www.google.com](http://www.google.com). actually consists of:

```
1 -   .       (hidden)
2 -   com
3 -   google
4 -   www
```

So uk.mail.yahoo.com. takes 5 steps to resolve. The limit is 127, so you could create 1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9.domain.com.

[Here's a link to the official standard which dictates this - RFC 1034](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034#section-3.1)